# 7 Wonders scoring question (Olympia B, copying a guild) on BSW

Tags: online, 7-wonders, scoring

On BrettspielWelt, I played Olympia (B) and built the 3rd wonder stage (copy a guild). The end score confused me, and I think BSW might have implemented the scoring wrong.

We were 3 players. Everyone had *one* guild.

Red had the science guild:

[image: Red player]

Blue:

[image]

Green (me):

[image]

---

As you can see, Red got no guild points. So I assume these are included in the score for science cards (didn't screenshot his science cards, unfortunately).

Blue got 5 guild points, which is correct (Red had 3 yellow cards, Green had 2).

Now, I (Green) got 10 guild points. **How comes that?** My own guild card gave me 6 points (2 browns + 3 greys + 1 purple). Now I get a guild card copy:

- If I'd copy Blue's guild, I'd get 4 points (Red's 3 yellow cards + Blue's 1 yellow card). Ha. That would be 10 points.
- But if I'd copy Red's guild, I'd have completed two science sets. So with this guild, I should have got 31 science points (instead of my 21).

Am I missing something or is this a bug on BrettspielWelt? **Why did the system copy Blue's guild for me, instead of Red's guild (which would have made me the winner)?**

Comment: Sounds like a design bug that it chooses the copy-card for you. It should have *you* choose it.

Comment: @Timwi: I think it's fine that the system chooses the card itself and not the player. Otherwise the player will do sums, which costs time. Of course the system should select the highest pointing card, though.

Comment: It sounds and looks like a bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with your assessment of how the scoring should've played out, so I would guess it is a bug, likely because copying that guild gives you 0 purple points so it thought that Blue's guild was better (failing to recognize that it gave you more science points).

Answer (score 4):

I agree, it should have copied Red's guild card for you. I can't think of any reason it shouldn't. I've never used BSW, but I'm assuming it makes this choice automatically. It sounds like a bug to me.

I hope their logic isn't looking at the value of the guild card, as scored by the owner, in order to determine which one is best for Olympia. As that would be incorrect for all guild cards (I think).

Comment: Yes, the system makes this choice automatically.